# 2 menus - Main menu, secondary menu and breadcrumbs

Tags: drupal, menu, drupal-7, breadcrumbs

A few questions regarding menus in Drupal 7, I've been looking for solutions but can't quite seem to find anyone else having a similar issue.

Using the Bartik theme:

I have 2 menus - one is the Main menu and allows for me to set children to pages. I have a secondary menu that I do not want to be in the main menu but I do want to allow it to have children. When I add pages, I cannot select my secondary menu in the dropdown to allow my secondary links to have children. I can't even select my secondary menu as an option.

Here are my questions:

- Can I allow for my secondary menu to have children without installing a module?
- Can I change a setting to allow me to select my secondary menu instead of the main menu when creating pages (without installing a module)?

```
<main menu>
    link 1
    link 2
        -- sublink 1
        -- sublink 2
<secondary menu>
    link 1
    link 2
        -- sublink 1
        -- sublink 2
```

- Can I allow for my secondary menu pages to have breadcrumbs without installing a module?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All menues have the same basic function, so yes you can add nodes to your secondary menu.

To make your secondary menu available, you need to change settings on each content type you want to use with this menu.

Go to admin > structure > content types

click "edit", go to "Menu Settings" tab, and enable the menu there.

Now when you create or edit a node of that type you should see that menu available.